# Trigger the $scope.submit() event of blueimp in angular programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, blueimp, angularjs-controller

When I use the submit() event of blueimp file uploader within the DOM, everything seems to work fine. i.e.:

```
<span class="btn" ng-click="submit()">Go</span>
```

However, calling `$scope.submit()` doesn't seem to work:

```
<span class="btn" ng-click="customSubmit()">Go</span>
```

```
$scope.customSubmit = function(){
  $scope.doSOmthingElses();
  $scope.submit();
}
```

$scope.submit() practically does nothing when called from the js rather than from the DOM.

Comment: Are you using [the Angular bindings](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js)? What does the rest of your controller code look like?

Comment: I do, I managed to hack my way around this by setting a scope variable to true each time the fileuploadsubmit event occurs, calling both my function and the blueimp function from the ng-click event, but returning from my custom function on the first line in case my scope variable indicates that the blueimp event has already occured.
Now it would be very nice to be able to access the server response data somehow.

Comment: You shouldn't have to hack anything if you're using the bindings properly. Again, share the rest of your controller code...

Comment: Do you need anything else in particular in order to help me with this problem?

Comment: Looking at the [source code for the Angular bindings](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js) it looks like you'll want to use one of the supplied Directives and/or the Provider. You haven't included any of your controller code, so I can't say whether or not you're doing things appropriately. Maybe [BlueImp's Angular example](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/angularjs.html) will be of some use to you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this , hope work for you

Controller.js

```
  app.module('app',[])
    .controller('appCtrl',function($scope){

    $scope.customSubmit = function(){
      $scope.doSOmthingElses();
      $scope.submit();
    }
    })
```

html

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body>
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <span class="btn" ng-click="customSubmit()"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my function was already at the same scope as the submit and as the file upload plugin instance.

Comment: Oh so you want to upload file with data on submit ...Try this directive  https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Comment: Which one?
I ended up with <input type="button" data-ng-click="submit();doSomethingElses()">

And checking a flag which truns to true on file select on the second function before executing it